# How can I calculate the average age of survey respondents?

Tags: survey, descriptive-statistics

A question in my survey asks about the age of respondents. Respondents are asked to choose one of these four ranges:

18-29
30-49
50-64
65 and over

How can I calculate the average age of respondents?

Comment: Since it's your survey, why don't you change it to ask the age to the nearest year (or even more precisely)?

Comment: @whuber, people often won't answer survey questions that ask for a specific age, income, etc.

Comment: @gung I understand that--but the question still needs to be asked.  Pondering the answer, and *why* we might ask for a range of ages, suggests some effective solutions.  In particular, it points to the (strong) advisability of not having any lengthy open-ended bins! It also can suggest creative solutions, such as handing the subject a die and asking them to roll it (privately) and add its value to their age. That would be far more precise than using these wide bins.

Comment: Not a duplicate of [How to find average and median age from an aggregated frequency table](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/138103/17230)?

Comment: @Scortchi In what sense is it not a duplicate?

Comment: Looks exactly like a duplicate to me, but I didn't know if you & @gung had spotted something different.

Comment: @Scortchi This question has been asked three or four times this year alone.  There are several duplicates: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/60256,  http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145777, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214576, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71169, *etc.*